# Cython: Signature not compatible with previous declaration

Tags: cython

File `orderbook.pyx`:

```py
from .constants import Side

cdef class OrderBook:
    cpdef set_order(self, side: Side, order: dict):
        pass
```

File `orderbook.pxd`:

```py
from .constants import Side

cdef class OrderBook:
    cpdef set_order(self, side: Side, order: dict)
```

File `constants.pxd`:

```py
cpdef enum Side:
    BUY = 1
    SELL = 2
```

However this leads to an error on the compilation step:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from .constants import Side


cdef class OrderBook:
    cpdef set_order(self, side: Side, order: dict):
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

orderbook.pyx:12:10: Signature not compatible with previous declaration

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

from .constants import Side

cdef class OrderBook:
    cpdef set_order(self, side: Side, order: dict)
                   ^
------------------------------------------------------------

./orderbook.pxd:5:19: Previous declaration is here
```